# AS3 class for a Flash Symbol

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, symbols

I am new to Flash, I am trying to create a class for a symbol.

I created a new Flash file, drop a DynamicText, convert this DynamicText to a Symbol called "TextBox1"

Then I created TextBox1.as in the same directory as the .fla I just created.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class TextBox1 extends MovieClip
    {

        public function TextBox1() 
        {
            trace("TextBox constructor");
        }

    }

}
```

I ran the Flash file but it doesn't display the message. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you associate the class with the symbol? Right click the symbol. Tick export for ActionScript and put TextBox1 in the class field.

Comment: Perfect! I knew it was something simple. Thank you Luke!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a blank class definition to use assets. Simply type in a class you want it to be called in Class under Linkage, and make sure the bass class is flash.display.MovieClip. When you press OK, Flash will come up with a box saying it will create a default definition for you, which is great. Now you can create instances of the class.

[creating a default class http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9799/flashwtf.png](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9799/flashwtf.png)

Comment: I agree that it's normally a bad thing to 'class out' a default asset. I think there may be more to the implementation than we are given in the original question. I hope there is some new functionality being added to TextField that is being sub-classed.